# Can we develop windows desktop apps using Devextreme

Tags: windows, html, visual-studio, cordova, devextreme

I have developed applications for Android and iOS using DevExtreme framework.

Can we develop windows desktop apps using Devextreme?
If yes please provide guidelines or steps to get started.
Please help on this.

Comment: I don't personally have any experience with DevExtreme, but a quick Google search of your question turned up results which would suggest: Yes, you can create desktop apps and widgets using DevExtreme, as it just uses HTML5 and jquery. I think Google will be your friend on this one, as this is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T135296

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. I suppose you use Visual Studio to develop windows apps. If so, the DevExtreme Multi-Channel project template supports [WinJS app](http://try.buildwinjs.com/).

Just create a new Multi-Channel app:

[image]

Then, you will be able to select WinJS project template:

[image]

The [DevExtreme documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/SPA_Framework/Application_Development/?version=15_2&approach=Knockout#SPA_Framework_Application_Development_Deployment_Deploy_as_a_WinJS_App) contains some information about WinJS development.

Also, I suppose, you can use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). Unfortunately, I have no experience with this tool. And there is one restriction here: Electron supports [Windows 7 and later](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/tutorial/supported-platforms/).